# dotnet test not loading resharper test adapter

Tags: .net-core, resharper, dotnet-test

We have an nunit3 test project that we're trying to run via command-line in dotnet core that is having problems being identified. In all our debugging we've not found an answer to fixing this.

Background: We build out these tests to test an API site after it's been deployed, alongside standard unit testing. So we package the test up as a DLL to run after we've built out the site, and configure it to run against the site. On our local machines, the tests can't be identified until we install Resharper on our Visual Studio.

After attempting a
`dotnet test "path\to\bin\release\Test.dll"`

we get the error:

> No test is available in path\to\bin\release\Test.dll. Make sure that test discoverer & executors are registered and platform & framework version settings are appropriate and try again.

> Additionally, path to test adapters can be specified using /TestAdapterPath command. Example  /TestAdapterPath:.

According to Resharper site, the tools require the run: `dotnet tool install -g JetBrains.ReSharper.GlobalTools`

doing so I've found the adapters at

> C:\Users\USER\.dotnet\tools\.store\jetbrains.resharper.globaltools\2020.3.2\jetbrains.resharper.globaltools\2020.3.2\tools\netcoreapp3.1\any\TestRunner\Adapters

but when trying to load a given adapter dll using /TestAdapterPath, it says it can't find it. any idea how to get this test running?

Answer (score 0):

Ensure your test project has a reference to the test adapter built in:

`<PackageReference Include="NUnit3TestAdapter" Version="3.17.0" />`

can be pulled from nuget package manager in Visual studio or placed into the  section with all other package references.

after this, run `dotnet test` against your built DLL